# CSS Flex issue with Javascript, element.style.display = "none" in a for loop

Tags: javascript, css, loops, flexbox, display

I have an Array declared:

```
var listChoices = [
    {nom: "Moi"},
    {nom: "Experiences"},
    {nom: "Savoir-Faires"}
];
```

I want to display those choices in a html/css page into X boxes in the middle of the screen that will interact under visitor's interaction (clicks mostly).

So I basically use Javascript to create an object

```
var Choice = {}
```

with all the CSS properties I want to be displayed for those 3 choices (I use an Array so that if I ever want to add an other box, I just have to add it into the Array and the entire page adjusts itself).

Important, I also did:

```
document.body.style.display = "flex";
document.body.style.justifyContent = "space-around";
```

My issue:

I use a for loop to create the three Choice objects based on listChoices, like:

```
for(var i = 0; i < listChoices.length; i += 1) {
    var choice = object.create(Choice);
    choice.style();
    choice.init();
    choice.logs();
    choice.react();
}
```

I basically put the CSS properties I wrote first in Choice.style into the newly created 3 choice objects. Then I create the 3  and places them with the Choice.init. Then the Choice.react is here to use functions I wrote to fade, moveDown and moveCenter on the three elements.

My issue is that when I want the "click" targeted element to remain and the other to fade, I would prefer to use a:

```
element.style.display = "none";
```

Rather than something like:

```
element.style.background = "transparent"; or element.style.background = "inherit";
```

The thing with the display = "none";  is that the remaining element acts weirdly. It shutters right and left in a frame or two and ends up in the middle after the two other elements disappeared.

So I want to know, does my problem comes from the for loop?

Is there a way to fix the position of the 3 elements and keep this position even after other flex related elements are removed?

Comment: Can't you just use visibility instead of display?

Comment: If you could post a [MCVE] that would help us try to reproduce and debug the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flex will calculate the position and layout of the items based on the visible content it has to work with, which is why you are noticing things get weird when using `display: none;` on some of the elements.

You could apply some clever margins based on the `nth-child` in order to allow you to use display: none, however, at that point you are going to be missing out on the benefits of Flexbox.

If it were me, I would visually hide the elements instead of using the display property.

Comment: First line probably resume it all. But there might be a way to attach that position Flex creates no ? Like getComputedStyle from the absolute position of the element ? (RIP Stevie <3)